# HttpStatus 500 Error in <jsp:forward page=""> tag

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build JSP project in Spring but while running it gives me following Exception -->

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 2

2:  jsp:forward page="login.form"

What to do??

Comment: Building a project in Spring not required to use jsp:forward.

Comment: I'm creating an spring-mvc application, for that I'm using jsp as view

Comment: Spring-mvc using a view behind you, you are messing something.

Comment: I'm just want to forward the request from 1 jsp page to another jsp page according to MVC principle

Comment: According to MVC principles you would forward from a controller (i.e. servlet) to a JSP, not from one JSP to another.